# Using React Native with AngularJS Components

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-native, angularjs-components

From what I understand, React Native essentially allows you extend the functionality of React components to include native UI elements for mobile platforms. Angular 1.5 introduced components as more or less simple, best-practice directives.

I have a web application already written in AngularJS, and it would be amazing to be able to produce native mobile applications using React Native without having to re-write the front-end of the application completely in React.

Is it possible to use React Native to add native UI elements to Angular components instead of React components? I apologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: No. You won't be able to just wrap Angular components in React Native and have a functioning app. Angular relies heavily on directives and templates and React doesn't offer you that. Build a React app the right way and use React. It might take a little bit more effort on your part but it is the correct way to do it. You will be able to reuse a lot of your core JS code though.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2016, you can now use angular and react native together. Check out [Angular2 + React native](http://angularjs.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/angular-2-react-native.html)

Comment: @Rjk Can we directly put angular components as it is using this? Consider I have written Angular components for web and I need to use it in mobile. Kindly help. I am new to this.

Comment: @PinkeshDarji like yogesh mentioned you need angular2

Comment: @Rjk So if I have angular2 components for web, And I will put it as it is in react native. Will that work?